# Saving data from Snapshot/Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save users fetched from Firebase Database.

I declared an array of users

```
var users = [User]()
```

then trying to fetch users and add them to the array of users

```
 func fetchUsers()
    {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
                let user = User(snapshot: snapshot)

                self.users.append(user)


        }, withCancel: nil)

    }
```

but the users are never added to the array. Whenever I do `user.count` in different parts of the code, it always say `0`.

I tried to do

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
   self.users.append(user)
}
```

but it's still not working.

I am new to Firebase and Swift. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you count the users after line where you appending it to array.

Comment: can you show us implementation of User(snapshot: snapshot) ?

Comment: Show your User class